# How to change the state mutability of a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

I'm a newbie in solidity coding, so please forgive me for my ignorance.

I'm trying to create a token based on [openzeppline](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) and while using the [HasNoTokens.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/HasNoTokens.sol) contract, I'm receiving the following warning in remix:

```
browser/mytoken.sol:446:3: Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure. function tokenFallback(address from_, uint256 value_, bytes data_) external {^Spanning multiple lines.
```

I reckon I've to change the way tokenFallback() function behaves. I'd greatful if someone could explain what is wrong here and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It is just telling you that you can use the modifier `pure` which basically means it is a function that only uses and modifies its arguments, and not any other value from the state of the contract.

See [this link](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#pure-functions)